Fixing a 3-way Switch in a 1950s House
Forgive me if I don't use the correct terminology. There is a 3-way switch in my house that doesn't function properly and it’s driving me crazy so I'd like to fix it. In order for one switch to work the other has to be "on." I should also say I'm not sure if a 3-way light is possible because both of the current switches installed are single pole and not the correct 3-way switches. Why would someone do that? Anyway, I would like to install the correct ones I have already purchased if possible. There are no ground wires and it appears to be 12/2 wiring in the boxes.
Box 1:
It contains three 12/2 cables. Originally, all three white wires were spliced together with a wire nut. I identified one of the black wires as the line wire using my voltage detector and have since marked it with red tape. The line wire was spliced with another black wire then connected to one of the screws on the single-pole switch. The remaining black wire was connected to the other screw.


Box 2:
It contains two 12/2 cables. Both white wires were spliced together with a wire nut. Each black wire was connected to a screw on the single-pole switch. Ignore my yellow tape.

How can I implement a 3-way switch here? Which wires get attached to the new device versus spliced together?
I'm assuming my line wire in Box 1 would get connected to the common screw like normal. I have a multimeter to help with continuity but I'm not sure what to test next.

I've taken the liberty of editing your question to keep it short and to-the-point, including removing some extra questions at the end that veer into off-topic territory. Feel free to [edit] to revise further if necessary.

TL;DR Smart Switches to the Rescue!
Correct 3-way switches require 3 wires. Two of those wires are travelers. The third switch could be:

Hot
Switched Hot
Neutral

depending on the switch and wire configuration.
But you only have two wires. You simply can't do legal 3-way switches with what you have. (Sometimes people cheat a bit by using ground as neutral and the other two wires as travelers, or other even crazier combinations, but those (a) are a code violation and (b) are very much not safe. So don't try that - though if you truly don't have ground you can't even try.)
You can't "add one wire" or (even if they are in the right place and parallel, which is unlikely) combine two cables together for 3-way wiring. All wires in each part of the circuit have to be in the same cable or conduit.
Except in an unfinished basement or similar room, running new cables is a pain, but in the 1950s (and a long time after that) that was the only option. Which sometimes result in strange switch configurations like the one you currently have.
However, there is good news thanks to smart switches. All the major switch manufacturers have them, but make sure you stick with switches that are properly listed (UL and ETL are the main things to look for in the US). For example (just an example, I have no connection with the manufacturer or Home Depot), the Leviton Decora Smart switch can be used with the Leviton Decora Smart Anywhere Switch Companion:

The great thing about this (and similar products from Lutron and others) is that it looks just like a regular switch but it can be installed anywhere. That includes your existing 2nd switch box or someplace entirely new, even if there are no wires in that location! The two switches communicate wirelessly and can be programmed so that they function like 3-way switches.
